# Mule more threads on VM transport

Tags: multithreading, jvm, mule

I'm struggling with how to affect (upward) the number of threads that a VM transport in Mule uses.  I've read the Tuning & Performance page in Mule's documentation, but something isn't clicking with me.

I have one flow that executes a JDBC call and then shoves the result set into VM queues using a foreach.

```
<foreach>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="checkService"/>
</foreach>
```

This is picked by another flow for processing, which consists of making an HTTPS call out and checking the return value.

```
<flow name="ExecuteTests" doc:name="ExecuteTests">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="checkService"/>
    <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"...
    ...etc.
</flow>
```

Some of those calls are quick, but some take up to 5 seconds.  What I'd like is for the ExecuteTests flow to use more threads to do the processing, but I only ever see threads 02-05 in the logs. I would have expected to see the number of threads used closer to the dispatcher thread pool for the outbound HTTPS connector...which I thought defaulted to 16.

I tried the following:

```
<vm:connector name="vmConnector">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="100" maxThreadsIdle="100"/>
</vm:connector>

<flow name="ExecuteTests" doc:name="ExecuteTests">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="checkService" connector-ref="vmConnector"/>
    ...etc.
```

but it made no difference.

Thinking that maybe the buffer for the inbound endpoint was messing with things, I tried:

```
<vm:connector name="vmConnector">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="100" maxThreadsIdle="100"/>
    <vm:queue-profile maxOutstandingMessages="1"/>  
</vm:connector>
```

but it didn't help either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your flow it can be observed that the issue is not with the threads.(I believe).

Normally the VM receiver threads are fast and they scale up based on the number of requests coming in. 
In the "ExecuteTests" flow there seems to be an outbound HTTP call. So it is the HTTP call that might be the cause for the delay.

But still if you want to increase the threads try  adding a dispatcher threading profile for a HTTP connector.

Also inorder to increase the number of threads for your flow processing use Flow threading profiles.

Like

```
<asynchronous-processing-strategy name="executeTestsStrategy" maxThreads="40"  minThreads="20"  />

<flow name="ExecuteTests" doc:name="ExecuteTests" processingStrategy="executeTestsStrategy">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="checkService"/>
    <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"...
    ...etc.
</flow>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought of that but my understanding of the default dispatcher thread pool for HTTP is that it was 16, which I'd be fine with.  That's why I'm puzzled about the fact that we never get above 4.  Nonetheless, I guess I'll start explicitly bumping that thread pool up and see what happens.  The tip on the flow thread pool is a good one, so I'll add that.

Comment: How'd it go? I'm kinda facing a similar issue.